# tf.saved_model.simple_save fail when converting from Keras model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I want to convert Keras saved model to saved_model which can be using with Tenserflow serving

I create model using pretrained model

```
feature_extractor_url = "https://tfhub.dev/google/tf2-preview/inception_v3/feature_vector/4"
feature_extractor_layer = hub.KerasLayer(feature_extractor_url, input_shape=self.img_dim)

feature_extractor_layer.trainable = False

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  feature_extractor_layer,
  layers.Dense(32, activation='relu'),
  layers.Dense(14, activation='softmax')
])
```

Then save the keras model to disk, then try to convert to saved_model

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub

MODEL_FOLDER = "../data/model"

tf.keras.backend.set_learning_phase(0)  # Ignore dropout at inference

EXPORT_PATH = './models/my_estimate/1'
with tf.keras.backend.get_session() as sess:
    model = tf.keras.models.load_model(MODEL_FOLDER, custom_objects={'KerasLayer': hub.KerasLayer})
    tf.saved_model.simple_save(
        sess,
        EXPORT_PATH,
        inputs={'input_image': model.input},
        outputs={t.name: t for t in model.outputs})
```

But I get the errors as below, I'm not sure how to fix it

```
FailedPreconditionError: 2 root error(s) found.
  (0) Failed precondition: Error while reading resource variable save_counter from Container: localhost. This could mean that the variable was uninitialized. Not found: Resource localhost/save_counter/N10tensorflow3VarE does not exist.
     [[{{node save_counter/Read/ReadVariableOp}}]]
     [[Adam/dense_1/kernel/v/Read/ReadVariableOp/_3137]]
  (1) Failed precondition: Error while reading resource variable save_counter from Container: localhost. This could mean that the variable was uninitialized. Not found: Resource localhost/save_counter/N10tensorflow3VarE does not exist.
     [[{{node save_counter/Read/ReadVariableOp}}]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I can fix the issue by adding 
`sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())`
after load model from file